# How to build an xcframework for Apple Silicon arm64 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, apple-silicon

I need to build my existing XCFramework for supporting the new Apple Silicon arm64 simulator..

When I archive using the following xcodebuild command:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme ${PROJECT_NAME}_MFI \
-archivePath "build/${PROJECT_NAME}_arm64simulator.xcarchive" \
-sdk iphonesimulator-arm64 \
-UseModernBuildSystem=YES
fi
```

Xcode would complain by:

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator-arm64" cannot be located.
```

I have also tried

```
-sdk ios-arm64-simulator
```

I am using Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33).

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your parameter to this:

**-arch arm64
-sdk iphonesimulator**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).